# Node Streams Pipeline Exception Handling: How to determine which stream raised the error

Tags: node.js, stream, pipeline

How can I tell (other than trying to interpret the stack trace programmatically, which stream raised the error thrown by a pipeline operation. It appears that (by design) all of the streams in the pipeline raise "error" events when an error thrown, which is fine, since that was one of the reasons for pipeline in the first place, but I cannot figure anyway of determining which stream was the actual source of the error.

Comment: A stream raises an “error” event when an error is thrown during stream processing. You should attach separate error handlers to each stream if the application needs to identify which stream that emitted the error programmatically. Streams “are event emitters” by design.

Comment: My testing shows that _ALL_ raise the same error event when an error occurs..

Comment: It isnt possible to differentiate between the streams based on the error object (unless you parse the stack trace), but it might be possible to attach one error handler per stream instead of a catch-all function? Such that each stream have their own unique error handler? Alternatively, the error could be rethrown with some additional meta